# Understanding Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), it says that

> Cauchy's formula shows that, in complex analysis, "differentiation is equivalent to integration"

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: Because you can compute all the derivatives in terms of the integrals.

Comment: @Randall Ah, right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A pleasant catchphrase, probably written by an undergrad physics student, but for integrations round closed contours under pretty special conditions: Cauchy’s integral theorem gives you results, when the conditions are right, in terms of derivatives. More interesting situations abound!